# How to write a Lambda with a for loop in it

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, lambda

I am trying to make an empty list the same length as the number of letters in a string:

```
string = "string"
list = []
#insert lambda here that produces the following:
# ==> list = [None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

The lambda should do the equivalent of this code:

```
for i in range(len(string)):
     list.append(None)
```

I have tried the following lambda:

```
lambda x: for i in range(len(string)): list.append(None)
```

However it keeps replying `Syntax Error` and highlights the word `for`.

**What is wrong with my lambda?**

Comment: lambdas can only contain expressions and `for` is a statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not multiplying?

```
>>> lst = [None]*5
>>> lst
[None, None, None, None, None]
>>> lst[1] = 4
>>> lst
[None, 4, None, None, None]
```

Why not list comprehension?

```
>>> lst = [None for x in range(5)]
>>> lst
[None, None, None, None, None]
>>> lst[3] = 9
>>> lst
[None, None, None, 9, None]
```

But… With lambda:

```
>>> k=lambda x: [None]*x
>>> lst = k(5)
>>> lst
[None, None, None, None, None]
>>> lst[4]=8
>>> lst
[None, None, None, None, 8]
```

Answer (score 5):

You want a lambda that takes a string `s` and returns a list of length `len(s)` all of whose elements are `None`. You can't use a `for` loop within a lambda, as a `for` loop is a statement but the body of a lambda must be an expression. However, that expression can be a list comprehension, in which you can iterate. The following will do the trick:

```
to_nonelist = lambda s: [None for _ in s]

>>> to_nonelist('string')
[None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a lambda for this.   All you need is:

```
[None] * len(string)
```